# Decina sta a dozzina come dieci sta a?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, single-words, numbers

Stamattina, leggendo un libro in inglese ho incontrato la parola *dozen* e l'ho ripetuta più volte in italiano, a voce, e mi è sorta la domanda in oggetto.

Qual è l'etimologia delle tre parole *dozzina*, *decina* e *dieci*? Esiste o è esistita la quarta parola?

Comment: Posso suggerire di modificare il titolo della domanda? La risposta a "_Decina sta a dozzina come dieci sta a?_" è semplicemente "dodici"; tuttavia la domanda è sull'etimologia delle parola, non sul suo significato.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alla fine della [voce "dozzina" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI04/00001001.jpg) puoi vedere l'etimologia di questo termine: viene dal francese *douzaine*, che a sua volta deriva da *douze*, che significa "dodici".

Lo stesso dizionario, però, ci avverte dell'esistenza del [vocabolo arcaico "dodicina"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI04/00000904.jpg) con lo stesso significato.

Per quanto riguarda ["decina"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI04/00000088.jpg), si tratta di una variante di "diecina", parola che proviene, effettivamente, da ["dieci"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI04/00000370.jpg), che ha origine nel numerale latino *decem*.

Comment: Quindi la risposta è che _decina_ sta a _dozzina_ come _dieci_ sta a _douze_, con l'unico problema che l'ultima parola non è italiana ma francese. Grazie per la risposta accurata e per i riferimenti. Direi che il tuo _Scusate se il mio italiano non è perfetto_ ha ormai poco senso (se mai l'ha avuto!). Complimenti!

Comment: *Dieci* viene da *decem*, con il “dittongo mobile” e quindi è regolare avere *decina* (senza dittongo) come *piede/pedone*, *cielo/celeste*; non in tutte le varietà di italiano il dittongo mobile si comporta allo stesso modo, quindi *diecina* può essere considerato una variante.